# Can a static scheduled loop block in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

The principal of static scheduling in OpenMP is simple: The scheduler assigns loop iterations to threads in a round robin fashion. Let's assume there are four threads: **t0**, **t1**, **t2**, **t3**.

The fifth iteration would again be assigned to **t0** if we use static scheduling. What happens if **t1** has not yet finished its work? Does the program block? Only a dynamic scheduler is allowed to distribute work in a more intelligent way (e.g. "Assign the next iteration to the thread that finished last").

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No!

Longer, version. OpenMP does not manage 'automatically' dependencies between thread. If you do have data dependencies between loop iterations it is your responsibility, as a developer, to make sure to place synchronization so that they are maintained when running in parallel.

You should look into the `ordered` directive if you need to maintain some sort of order within iterations.

Comment: I am not talking about dependencies. The amount of work is just not distributed equally and t0 is still working, though it should get the next iteration. 

If nothing is blocked, how does static scheduling then work? Does the next iteration then is assigned to **t1**

Comment: With static scheduling each thread gets an equal slice of the iterator range (statically). So if you have N iterations in your loop and T threads, each will get N/T iterations. Threads that have completed their iterations will wait at the end of the loop. if you use the `nowait` directive in your `#pragma omp for` then threads will continue until the end of the parallel region or `barrier`.

Comment: If you know your iterations may have different amount of work, the best option would be to use the `dynamic` schedule.